# Insert element into order position of array?

Tags: php, arrays

All values of array $A are string the same length.

```
$A  = Array
(
    [0] => 03
    [1] => 04
    [2] => 05
    [3] => 06
  //  [4] => 07 // "07" before "04" position
    [4] => 04
    [5] => 05
    [6] => 06
  //   [8] => 07 // "07" before "08" position
    [7] => 08
    [8] => 03
    [9] => 04
    [10] =>  05
    [11] => 06
    [12] => 07 // it is existing
    [13] => 08
) ;
```

I want to Insert the "07" element if `it is not existing` before "04" or "08" position.start from position 1

So It will be after changed

```
$A  = Array
(
    [0] => 03
    [1] => 04
    [2] => 05
    [3] => 06
    [4] => 07 // just appended
    [5] => 04
    [6] => 05
    [7] => 06
    [8] => 07 // just append
    [9] => 08
    [10] => 03
    [11] => 04
    [12] =>  05
    [13] => 06
    [14] => 07
    [15] => 08
) ;
```

Anybody know how to do this ,help me please?

Comment: "append" means to _insert at the end_. You are talking about _insertion_ more generally.

Comment: @Tomalak I do believe he is talking about homework more generally...

Comment: @newbie can you explain why (in our expected result) 07 is only sometimes injected before 04, and not allways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not the most beautiful solution, but should do the job:

```
$b = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($A);$i++){
    $b[] = $A[$i];
    if(($i<count($A) - 1) && ($A[$i+1]<$A[$i] || ($A[$i+1] == '08')) && $A[$i] < '07')
        $b[] = '07';
}
var_dump($b);
```

Comment: THANS ,YOUR CONDITION if(($i<count($A) - 1) && ($A[$i+1]<$A[$i] || ($A[$i+1] == '08') ||$A[$i+1]==$A[$i] ) && $A[$i] < '07') IT'S OKAY.

Answer (score 4):

There would be "prettier" ways to do this but, as intended...

1. iterate the array
2. if the current value is equal to 7 minus 1 you will insert a new value there
3. create a function "insert_into_array" that:
   a) Splits your array in two (look at [array_chunk](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php))
   b) POPs your element to the end of the first array ([array_pop](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php))
   c) merges your two arrays back ([array_merge](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php))

I've abstained from writing any code as this is probably homework and, writing code, even if you're not really deep thinking the problem will push you a long way to passing the exam...

Answer (score 0):

First, find the gaps in your array, that is the positions where there's `06` but not a following `07`:

```
$positions = array();
foreach ($A as $k => $v) {
    if (isset($last) && $last != $v - 1 && $last == '06') {
        $positions[] = $k;
    }
    $last = $v;
}
```

Then, insert them:

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($positions as $pos) {
    array_splice($A, $pos + ($count++), 0, '07');
}
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

```
//make sure the array is numeric:
$A = array_values($A);
foreach(array('04','08') as $search){
    $positions = array_keys($A,$search);
    rsort($positions);
    foreach($positions as $key){
        if($key==0 || $A[$key-1] != '07'){
             array_splice($A,$key,0,'O7');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In 2017**, I've found 2 beautiful methods that is part of `nette\utils` package.

- [`Arrays::insertBefore()`](https://github.com/nette/utils/blob/6e85aef6b2a18e7dcfa91072db6799dba5d350a4/src/Utils/Arrays.php#L90-L98)
- [`Arrays::insertAfter()`](https://github.com/nette/utils/blob/6e85aef6b2a18e7dcfa91072db6799dba5d350a4/src/Utils/Arrays.php#L101-L110)

They do job perfectly!

Just run:

```
composer require nette/utils
```

and use `Arrays` class or inspire in their code.